# Compile C++ without CRT

Tags: c++, native

Basically the title says it all; I want to COMPLETELY disable the CRT when I am coding in C++.

I want to be able to run the exe on Win98 as well as all the other ones.
Just plain NATIVE C++.

The compiler I am using is Visual Studio. However, I am willing to change if it's required.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to disable the CRT on Windows 98?

Comment: I phrased it badly; I want to compile the executable without using CRT.

Comment: Sure, but I guess I'm interested in why you're trying to do this.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "you can't".  But back up a stage and explain to us (a) what your program does in broad outline, (b) the concrete problems you are running into, (c) why you think disabling the CRT will solve them, and (d) why you think you need to support operating systems that are past their vendor end-of-life.

Comment: Programs with no input and no output can be of little interest.

Comment: If you don't understand why I am asking these questions, please read  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem carefully.

Comment: Maybe the OP is got the wrong term and is talking about CLR instead of CRT.

Comment: The problem I am running to is that my program won't run on win2k:
".exe is not a valid win32 application" -- I thought removing CRT will fix it, but perhaps there is another fix.

Comment: @drescherjm I keep on accidentally hitting enter when I try to make a line break. (forgetting to press SHIFT) -- Fixed now.

Comment: You probably have to use an older version of Visual Studio. VS 2013 supported XP via the v120_xp toolset but I am not sure that supported win2k.

Comment: By no means removing CRT is going to help you. It's just that modern Visual C++ compiler can't create executables for Win98. And think about it - Win98 is 20 years ago! Why even think about supporting it?

Comment: "my program won't run on win2k". It will also not work on Linux or Mac OS X. No big deal, people somehow cope with this. If you want it on win2k, build a version for win2k using a win2k toolchain.

Comment: @n.m., I guess, one would be hard-pressed to find the toolchain for win2k nowadays.

Comment: @SergeyA I think you can find them on NSDN.

Comment: You can still get Visual C++ 2.0 and VS.net 2002 among others from MSDN

Comment: `The problem I am running to is that my program won't run on win2k: ".exe is not a valid win32 application" -- I thought removing CRT will fix it` then you're having an XY problem like above. The message means the exe file is corrupted, or just isn't x86 binary so obviously it can't be run

Comment: Related / Maybe duplicate: [Visual Studio 2015: Compile C/C++ without a runtime library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217241/visual-studio-2015-compile-c-c-without-a-runtime-library/39220245)

Comment: Also replying to all the "XY problem" / "You can't" commenters, for the stated question of "C++ without CRT" (I am not sure about Win98 compatibility), [here's a CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15156/tiny-c-runtime-library) that goes into some of the reasoning as to why somebody might want to do this, and some source code showing how to do it. Sometimes topics like this are just interesting conceptually in their own right, even if most programs won't be built with custom runtimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard helping without knowing what you need to do, in general case you cannot remove CRT, [here's why](http://www.drdobbs.com/avoiding-the-visual-c-runtime-library/184416623):

- Entry point (gets input from console)
- Provide common functions used
  in C and C++

That means that without CRT you won't be able to use neither stdio (unless you link it later manually), **also you cannot run the application in the console**.

A way you can remove CRT is by creating a static library, this is near to pure native C++ as much as possibile, if you don't link external libraries inside it (well, a object file is much more near to navite C++ than a static library).

Depending on operative system you may not even be able to call a function within the binary without the CRT (in example Windows). So if you want just to avoid binary overhead the best bet is having a static/dynamic library wich is linked to some other "launcher" or just dynamically invoked (that needs a way to retrieve an entry point anyway).

Again, hard to tell what you need if you don't give enough details.

EDIT:

If you need to run on older win98 then use a compiler that supports win98 and specify you want to compile for win98 using compiler flags.

Comment: We already know from the comments what is **real** OP problem.

Comment: Those comments were added while writing the answer (SE don't reload if new comments added on question)

Comment: Yes, but once you know it, you can actually edit the answer to answer the actual question.

Answer (score 13):

You can remove all references to the CRT provided by Microsoft and replace it with your own custom lightweight CRT.  Instructions to do so are somewhat lengthy, and are summed up nicely with accompanying source code here:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15156/tiny-c-runtime-library

The instructions are a bit out-of-date, but I managed to get portions of the `tlibc` to work on Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10.  Everything except the `FILE` API seems to compile and work.  The jist of steps to follow were:

1. Create a Console Application project.
2. Disable linking of all standard libraries (`/NODEFAULTLIB`)
3. Disable all Compiler Runtime Checks (RTC)

At that point, the tilbc sources compiled and ran (sans outdated FILE portions).

---

That said, the OP's *actual* problem was something very different.  The CRT is not to blame for the error `.exe is not a valid win32 application`.  This error occurs long before any code from the binary is actually executed, which includes the CRT executed prior to `main()`/`winmain()`.  It most typically occurs when trying to run an `x64` binary on an `x86` operating system.  In theory even the Visual Studio 2017 toolchain can build applications suitable for Windows 2000 and Win98, so long as you use the correct SDK version flags when including `<windows.h>`.

Even in cases where the wrong SDK or compiler flags are used, the error reported would be something else -- most likely a failed DLL load or a popup error reading something along the lines of *"the program could not start"* and followed by a compatibility mode offering.

Answer (score 3):

Guide - How to avoid C/C++ runtime on Windows:

https://hero.handmade.network/forums/code-discussion/t/94-guide_-_how_to_avoid_c_c++_runtime_on_windows

Answer (score 2):

You can statically link the C++ runtime using the correct project settings, but even then you'll at best get it working on Windows XP.

You can find out how to statically link the standard library [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx), but just in case the link dies:

> To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment
>
> 1) Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see How to: Open Project Property Pages.
>
> 2) Expand the C/C++ folder.
>
> 3) Select the Code Generation property page.
>
> 4) Modify the Runtime Library property.

If you ***really*** want to get it working on Windows 98, then you need to use an older version of Visual Studio and do something like the above.

Comment: VC++ very much uses CRT for native C++ code, the library in question is called `msvcrt<toolchain-version>.dll`. Note the three letters `c` `r` and `t` in the middle.

Comment: How do I make my exe able to run on older Windows versions then?
I want it to support all Windows versions.

Comment: @Prionum, see my answer, basically you need a compiler that support the windows version you are targeting and you need to do at least some different builds. I'm not even sure most recent Visual Studio still supports win 98. You should probably put a new question asking wich compilers support Win98 (or the systems you want) and how to setup correct project settings.

Comment: See if you can purchase a copy of Visual Studio 2003.

Comment: @DarioOO last I checked, the more recent version of Visual Studio include special support for XP if you ask for it, but no earlier than that.

Comment: yes win 2k or less is TOO old (XP is already too old, and vista by the way is bad supported anywhere)

Comment: I still have a lot of sympathy for both software vendors who feel they still need to support XP, and end-users who feel they still cannot afford to move to something newer than XP.  But Win98 and Win2K are Right Out.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible, however, there are many disadvantages so I do not recommend it (I will not be getting into them).

Do you have a reason for targeting Win98? Almost no one uses it anymore. I recommend Windows Vista+, however, it's entirely up to you.

First of all, you will need to disable Optimization, set the RT lib to MT, disable security checks (this will make your application less secure!), among other things. To do that go to C/C++ settings and add `/Od /MT /GS-` to the command line.

Next go to Code Generation and set Enable C++ Exceptions to No.
After that go to linker and add `/NODEFAULTLIB` to the command line.
Finally, navigate to Advanced and set the entry point.

After that you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using different compiler's such as Symantec C++ 7.5 or Digital Mars C++.

I have programs made by the Symantec compilers that run flawlessly even in Win 11.

In fact hats-off to the author of the 90'a app pfe32 (programmers file editor) that runs' on any Windows version.