# Visual Studio 2015: Compile C/C++ without a runtime library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, crt

Is there a way of compiling C/C++ with Visual Studio 2015 without using any runtime library?

I need to compile without a runtime library because I'm creating my own runtime library (for my OS).

There are options on C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library
but I want an option that says "none".

I'm aware of loosing a lot of features that are in the CRT.

Comment: Last I heard, it was not possible to compile an OS kernel with Visual Studio - it's simply not designed for it, and many parts of it assume you're running on WIndows.

Comment: Also related: Visual Studio produces executables in the PE file format.  What file format does your OS run?

Comment: Also: start here: http://wiki.osdev.org/Visual_Studio and proceed directly to "Custom C++ Runtime"

Comment: It is technically possible, as long as (a) the code doesn't make any CRT or Win32 calls, and (b) you override the default entry point (_DllMainCRTStartup or _WinMainCRTStartup) which pulls in the CRT by default. As commented already, however, you'll still end up with a binary in PE format using the Win32 ABI.

Comment: @dxiv: Though there is a pretty decent chance that PE is what's desired, since that's (at least sort of) what UEFI supports/uses.

Comment: This seems like a pretty specific question about a programming tool. I cleaned up the question. Not sure why it's downvoted.

Comment: One way to find more info: `link /? | find /i "lib"`. Another way is to search for questions about smallest executable for Windows and Unixland.

Comment: Related forum post with useful information on this topic: [Handmade Hero forums: Guide - How to avoid C/C++ runtime on Windows](https://hero.handmade.network/forums/code-discussion/t/94-guide_-_how_to_avoid_c_c++_runtime_on_windows)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To compile your app without C-Runtime Library (CRT) use `/MT`, `/NODEFAULTLIB` linker options and redefine entry point at `Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point` to function defined in your code, e.g. `rawMain`. The signature is:

```
DWORD CALLBACK rawMain();
```

Without C-runtime library you are not allowed to use it's functions, like `malloc`, `free`, `memset`, etc. You should implement all the used CRT functions by yourself. E.g. you can replace usage of `malloc` by `VirtualAlloc()` and `free` by `VirtualFree()`.

To check that C-runtime is not linked to your application use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Hint for further investigation, CRT implementation of the main function is located in `VC\crt\src\vcruntime\exe_common.inl` (VS2015)

Comment: @SeeSoftware Make sure `Linker -> Input -> Ignore All Default Libraries` is set to `Yes` and check that `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` list doesn't contain any CRT libraries. Also make sure you don't include any [`C++ Standard Library Header Files`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tkse1h.aspx) because in this case Standard C++ Library will be linked in automatically.

Comment: i had the correct settings but forgott to change debug to release

Comment: In my case we used IDA and wanted to remove all the `_scrt` functions. We did it like describe: `Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point` and we had "main" function so added it as "main" and now it removed all these functions.